# Normalizr Union is missing id of nested item

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

I have the following schemas defined:

```js
export const user = new schema.Entity('users', {}, { idAttribute: 'username' });

export const galleryImage = new schema.Entity('images', {
  user,
});

export const stream = new schema.Entity('streams', {
  user,
});

export const thing = new schema.Union({
  images: galleryImage,
  streams: stream,
}, (input, parent) => (parent.type === 'gallery_image' ? 'images' : 'streams'));

export const post = new schema.Entity('posts', {
  user,
  thing,
});
export const feedSchema = new schema.Array(post);
```

Basically, my post scheme "thing" is polymorphic and can either be a GalleryImage or a Stream. They're identical, but I would like to be able to differentiate between them after normalizing and it seems easy to do. My problem is that even though I have defined the `idAttribute`, it is undefined in that nested `thing` after normalizing.

Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Can you add some sample data so your code can be run?

Comment: Oddly enough, when I try it in a Codebox, it works without fail. Huh.

Comment: I set up a Codebox, but for some reason it works there as opposed to my local setup: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-tu-l57id

Comment: @PaulArmstrong It seems to work once using JSON.stringify, but it does not work within React. Still detects it as undefined in the render.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that console.log fooled me and the cause of my issues was reselect.

Answer (score 0):

My issue actually wasn't with normalizr. It seems that my initial assumption was wrong because of console.log not outputting the right values.

I had set my dispatches in the wrong order, which resulted in users being unavailable to reselect. That would actually be the cause of the issues.